# WPAdverts - How to limit form submission 10 per month

Tags: forms, limit

I currently use wpadverts plugin and wants to limit the submission to 10 submit / month.

How can I do that?

I think I need to make a new row like "form_submissions" in "wp_usermeta" and store every time when the user submitted the form and make a cron task to delete the row value after a month.

And I need to query the row value on the form submit page like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `form_submission` FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = $user_id");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($row['form_submission'] > 10) {
        // can't submit the form because you already have 10 post
    } else {
        // you can submit the form
    }
```

Or I'm totally lost? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: with WordPress you can use `update_user_meta` and `get_user_meta` to make it easier on yourself instead of writing queries every time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And how can I add +1 to the current value if I'm using update_user_meta? So I wants to add +1 every time when user submit new post I tried `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'form_submission', 'form_submission' +1, true ); ` but doesn't work. It will always be 1

Comment: `$value = get_user_meta($user_id, 'form_submission', true); if (!$value) {$value = 1;} else {$value = $value + 1);} update_user_meta($user_id, 'form_submission', $value);`

Comment: Okay, I did it, thanks for your help. Can you write an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `get_user_meta` and `update_user_meta`:

```
$value = get_user_meta($user_id, 'form_submission', true); 
if (!$value) {$value = 1;} else {$value = $value + 1;}
if ($value < 11) {
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'form_submission', $value);
} else {
    // too many form submissions
}
```

You could also expand on this to store the submission month too if you don't want to use a cron job.

```
$month = get_user_meta($user_id, 'submission_month', true);
$value = get_user_meta($user_id, 'form_submission', true); 

if ($month && ($month != date('m',time())) ) {
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'submission_month', date('m', time());
    $newmonth = true;
} else {$newmonth = false;}
if (!$value || $newmonth) {$value = 1;} else {$value = $value + 1;}
if ($value < 11) {
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'form_submission', $value);
} else {
    // too many form submissions
}
```